# How do I edit a product attribute using PHP during a cart checkout in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, attributes, e-commerce

I have a two part question about customizing my Magento store.

When someone buys a downloadable product, I want to generate a licence code and include it in the invoice.

I have added a product attribute called ‘license_code’ to my product’s default attribute set and I want to set its value with php when a customer checks out.

What is the event to observe that will let me access the products in the cart just after they are purchased but before the invoice is created?

I also need to know what script to use to set a product’s attribute value during that event.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I got it figured out.

I set up my event observers as follows:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_item_save_before>
        <observers>
            <downloadable_observer>
                <class>Licensing_Catalog_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>generate_licenses</method>
            </downloadable_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_item_save_before>
</events>
```

and then my observing function as:

```
public function generate_licenses($observer)
{
    $orderItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
    $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
    $options['licence_code'] = 'YOUR-DOWNLOADABLE-CODE-HERE';
    $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);

  return $this;
}
```

Thank you so much for the help, clockworkgeek!

Comment: Correction:  the event is sales_order_item_save_before

Comment: In current Magento version Supported events in order are:  sales_order_load_after      ,                   sales_order_save_before   ,                         sales_order_save_after    ,                         sales_order_delete_before

Answer (score 2):

Possible [events](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events) are `sales_order_place_before` or `sales_convert_quote_*`.

You cannot save your 'license_code' attribute because that will affect all products, a product does not store it's values when ordered. Instead a better idea would be to manipulate the options of an order item.

```
function salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $orderItem = $observer->getOrderItem();
    $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
    $options['licence_code'] = YOUR-DOWNLOADABLE-CODE-HERE;
    $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
}
```

Retrieving the code later is essentially the same process with `getProductOptions()`, the order item objects are already used on the order view pages so are easy to find and use in your theme.

Comment: Thank you.  This is really helpful, and probably what I need to save the product options.  However, now I'm stuck trying to get the items from this observer.

I've added an event observer for 'sales_order_place_before' but I can't figure out the function to use to get an array of items from $observer.

Comment: I meant for the event to be `sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item` but I see you have your answer now. Congratulations. There are always several events for each action so there are plenty to choose from.